# file order variation in ext3 filesystem

Tags: readdir, ext3

I have a program whose output depends on how file order are returned by readdir. Is there any way to simulate different file return order over ext3

Comment: Without additional constraints, my solution would be to hard-code different permutations in a bunch of test cases. `./myprog file2 file1.txt file3; ./myprog file3 file2 file1.txt; ./myprog file1.txt file2 file3; ./myprog file1.txt file3 file2`

Comment: Still, add a mock readdir to the test suite which returns one of a hard-coded list of alternatives.